# Всё по 100 рублей! Какой тип предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Рекламное объявление:

> Всё по 100 рублей!

Какой это тип предложения? Где здесь подлежащее и сказуемое?
Отличается ли этот пример от следующего:

> Квартиры от 3 миллионов рублей!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Всё по 100 рублей!*- я воспринимаю это предложение как двусоставное  полное нераспространённое: (что?) всё - подлежащее, (каково?) по 100 рублей (то есть дешёвое). Можно его воспринять и как эллиптическое, ведь можно восполнить: *Всё **можно купить** (продаётся,предлагаем) по 100 рублей!*.

*Квартиры от 3 миллионов рублей!* - это предложение видится мне номинативным, так и хочется подставить "вот": *Вот  квартиры от 3 миллионов рублей!* Если б это было эллиптическое, здесь было бы тире: *Квартиры  - от 3 миллионов рублей!*

Так что примеры эти всё же различаются.